# Powershell script to copy files based on filename

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that contains several thousand files. I would like to write a Powershell script that loops through the files and copies each file whose filename contains a specific keyword. In pseudocode:

```
For each file in C:\[Directory]
    If filename contains "Presentation" Then
        copy file in C:\[Directory 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply like this ?

```
copy-item "C:\SourceDir\*Presentation*" "C:\DestinationDir"
```

or like this :

```
copy-item "C:\SourceDir\*" "C:\DestinationDir" -Filter "*rrrr*"
```

But a risk exist if you have a directory with "presentation" in his name into the source directory. Then take all method proposed here and add -file in get-childitem command.
Like in this short version of Robdy code :

```
gci "C:\SourceDir" -file | ? Name -like "*Presentation*" | cpi -d "C:\DestinationDir"
```

Answer (score 1):

That code should do the trick:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\source\folder"
$files | Where-Object Name -Like "*Presentation*" | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\path\to\destination\folder"
```

Of course can be written in one line but I put in two for visibility.

Edit: as Esperento57 pointed out, you might want to add `-ItemType File` to `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to not include folders with 'Presentation' in their name. Also, depending on your needs you might also want to use `-Recurse` param to include files in subfolders.

If you have files in subfolders and you want to keep the path in destination folder you'll have to change the script a bit to something like:

```
Copy-Item -Destination $_.FullName.Replace('C:\path\to\source\folder','C:\path\to\destination\folder')
```

And for the above you'll have to make sure that folders are actually created (e.g. by using `-Force` for `Copy-Item`.

Comment: You should be add -file to Get-ChildItem, because if you have a dir with "Presentation" in his name... ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. There's even more possible scenarios there like `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` (if files are in subfolders), `Copy-Item -Force` (if you need to create folder/recreate folder path in destination folder).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$src = "Dir1"
$dst = "Dir2"

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter "*Presentation*" -Recurse | % {
    New-Item -Path $_.FullName.Replace($src,$dst) -ItemType File -Force
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($src,$dst) -Force
}
```

Comment: You should be add -file to Get-ChildItem, because if you have a dir with "Presentation" in his name... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Your\Directory" -File -Filter *YourKeyWordToIsolate* | 
Foreach-Object { Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Your\New\Directory" }
```

... but, of course, you'll need to fill in some of the blanks left open by your pseudocode example.

Also, that's a one-liner, but I inserted a return carriage for easier readability.

Comment: You should be add -file to Get-ChildItem, because if you have a dir with "Presentation" in his name... ;)

Comment: @Esperento57 Good point.  Updated based on your recommendation.  It's also worth noting that overwriting existing files could be problems as well... but for simplicity, that should be addressed separately I think.